# JMX Data Agent to support remoting-jmx protocol with WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I was trying to monitor jboss EAP 6.0/jboss AS 7 MBeans in WS02 BAM 2.2.0 using JMX Data Agent. I followed the [tutorial](http://magnus-k-karlsson.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-remote-connect-jconsole-to-jboss.html) to expose JBOSS MBeans, remotely in jconsole.

In WSO2 BAM while adding JMX Server Profile, I enter the URL:

```
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://{host_name}:{port}]
```

It says protocol is not supported. I suspect protocol remoting-jmx is not supported, where as in previous case, I see rmi protocol was supported. How can I import Remote JBOSS AS 7 MBean to WSO2 BAM 2.2.0 ?